# Pass static property into Generic input parameter

Tags: c#

I am getting the following error when I try to pass in x.Bar in the RegisterMethod.

> Member 'TestProject2.Foo.Bar.get' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

**Q. Is it possible at all to keep Bar property static?**

```
namespace TestProject2
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {

            RegisterMethod<Foo, string>(x => x.Bar); <-- error here

        }

        static void RegisterMethod<TSelf, TProp>(Expression<Func<TSelf, TProp>> expression)
        {
            var member_expression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
            if (member_expression == null)
                return;

            var member = member_expression.Member;
            if (member.MemberType != MemberTypes.Property)
                return;

            var property = member as PropertyInfo;
            Console.WriteLine(property.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(property.DeclaringType);

        }

    }

    public class Foo
    {
        private string _bar;
        public static string Bar  <-- would very much want to keep this static
        {
            get { return _bar; }
            set { _bar = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Bar` is a propert of `Foo`, not of `x`. Your problem here is in the implementation of `Bar`. You are trying to access an instance field from a static property.

Comment: Why do you need Bar to be static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know the type, you can replace `x.Bar` with `Foo.Bar`, like this:

```
RegisterMethod<Foo, string>(x => Foo.Bar);
```

This should take care of the error message. The reason you see the error in the first place is that when you access a static members through an instance syntax, you are sending compiler a mixed message. On one hand, you're telling it that you think that `Bar` is a member property; on the other hand, you have declared it as a `static` property. Inconsistencies like this commonly happen during unsuccessful refactorings, so the compiler triggers an error to have you double-check your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the call to `RegisterMethod`:

```
RegisterMethod(x => Foo.Bar);
```

You don't need to specify the type parameters, they are deduced using member inference.

However you will need to extend the `RegisterMethod` method to not always assume a `MemberExpression`.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your bolded question:

> **Q. Is it possible at all to keep Bar property static??**

In order to keep `Bar` static, you **MUST** make `_bar` static. it doesn't even make sense otherwise.

`x.Bar` does not make sense either when `Bar` is static.  You'd access `Bar` with `Foo.Bar`

A static property is not associated with any particular instance of your class.  There is only ever one instance of that static p

---

If you need `_bar` to be non-static and `Bar` to be static, there is something fundamentally wrong with your design.